# Mix static files into WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm migrating a previously-static site to WordPress 4.3.1. Most things are working fine, but I have one odd case: I need `example.com/foo/` to be dynamic, but I need `example.com/foo/bar/` to be static. I've created a `/foo/bar/index.html` to handle `example.com/foo/bar/`, but now `example.com/foo/` is giving a 403 Forbidden code.

I also need `example.com/foo/bar/` to show up in the menu, which I've accomplished by adding a dynamic `example.com/foo/bar/` as well (deleting this doesn't help).

The `example.com/foo/` page still exists and can be edited in admin. Why am I getting 403 and how can I fix it?

Comment: It is the default document on your web server who need to be configured, to get the correct answer we need server infos. It seems you don't have your old rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the WordPress Apache rewrite rules pass everything on to WordPress which *does not exist as a file or a directory* on the filesystem, which is what the two `RewriteCond` rules check for. But you *do* have a directory corresponding to `/foo/` on the filesystem, causing Apache to handle it internally.

To resolve this, you'll need to tell Apache explicitly to pass this on to WordPress (and do this with any other URLs that might have directories masking them from the first rewrite rule).

Add a new section of directives just before the end of the `IfModule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/foo/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/bar/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/baz/"
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

As for the WordPress menu, you shouldn't add blank pages to add entries to it. Instead, just create custom menu entries with the desired URLs to your static pages. Click on Custom Links in the menu editor and add the desired information.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify my DirectoryIndex configuration.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
```

These is my /etc/workpresss/access rules for WordPress with mixed static content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Content rewrites go here

    # Serve static content
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Use WordPress for rest of the content
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Edit: The 403 is a forbidden access message.  This may be an ACL in Apache or a permissions issue on the WordPress directories.  The reason for the 403 may be recorded in the Apache error log.

As you have an isolated directory tree, you should be able to use a `Location` or `Directory` directive for the static code. This is a variation on one I use.

```
<Location /foo/bar/>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Comment: This doesn't help. `DirectoryIndex` is probably irrelevant here because the static content is in `/foo/bar/` and I'm having trouble with `/foo/`. There is nothing in `/foo/` other than the `bar/` directory. Your rewrite rules don't help either (and are mostly the same as WordPress's default rules except that WordPress has one additional rule that rewrites `/index.php` to `/`).

Comment: @Viko See edit above.  My configuration doesn't rewrite `/index.php` to `/` as WordPress handles that.